# Почему ни один плагин wordpress не выводит микроразметку?

Tags: wordpress, микроразметка, yoast

Устанавливал плагины: `Yoast SEO`, `Schema`, `Schema & Structured Data for WP & AMP`. Указывал в каждом все необходимые пункты, никаких ошибок не выводится ни в консоль браузера, ни при выполнении скриптов php (`debug` - `true`), но также и не выводится сгенерированная схема. В каждом руководстве говорится о том, что достаточно сделать базовую настройку (кроме последнего) и плагин сам добавит либо в `header`, либо перед `</body>` код разметки, однако ничего этого не происходит.

Даже когда в `Schema & Structured Data for WP & AMP` попробовал использовать Custom schema и вставить json-ld формат - никаких ошибок, но и код не вставлен. Проверял как на локальном, так и на внешнем сервере - результат один. Надо ли использовать какие-то сниппеты или shortcode? Почему не добавляется сгенерированная схема ни в `header`, ни перед закрывающимся `body`?

Схема нужна в формате JSON-LD:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  ...
}
</script>
```

Comment: А с чего ты решил, что микроразметка будет в коде страницы в `script`? И зачем тебе такое нужно? (Чую проблему молотка...)

Comment: @SeVlad В каждом руководстве, как на том же youtube, так и на самих документациях указано, что это подсоединяется в коде элемента автоматически. Если вы знаете причину, то укажите её, а если нет, то вот та же документация от [yoast](https://yoast.com/features/structured-data/) по схеме

Comment: Указанные плагины отлично работают и вставляют указанный код. Скорее всего, проблема в самопальной теме, которая, к примеру, не вызывает get_header(). Как результат, не срабатывают хуки, на которых плагины производят вывод. И JS тут ни при чём, всё происходит в PHP. Смените тему на стандартную и посмотрите, выводится ли ld+json.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Да, это так! НО! В самопальной теме, есть код `<?php get_header(); ?>`... Так что не до конца понятны какие хуки срабатывают

Comment: Значит, чего-то еще нет. Берите в руки Query Monitor и сравнивайте хуки, сработавшие в стандартной теме и в вашей.

Comment: @Pashok за линк на мануал спасибо, но там нет упоминаний ни `script`  ни `json`.  Я (был) не уверен, что плагины это делают. Но если KAGGDesign подтверждает, что должны, то у меня нет оснований не верить этому. (а мои сомнения основаны на опыте - не раз мне доказывали что якобы микроразметки нет, но это было не так, что подтверждалось тем же https://validator.schema.org)

Comment: @SeVlad Да, KAGGDesign мне помог в этом и осталось оформить. Но про то, что плагины выводят эту разметку через скрипты на js, например ajax, я не говорил. Уточнил лишь, что ошибок в консоли не было, да и формат не просто `json`, а `json-ld`, который при генерации страницы добавится как в примере вопроса

Comment: @Pashok я про js ничего не говорил. Я говорил что на той странице нет указанных вхождений текста. А твой вопрос именно в этом.